# Non-linear optimization giving error NMaximize::nrnum

Tags: mathematical-optimization, warning-messages, nonlinear

I am trying to solve the following non-linear optimization problem:

Here is my code:

```
Clear[f, y1, y2, y3 , z1, z2, z3];
f = 
  ((0 y1 - 10 y2 + 90 y3)^(0.9) (0 z1 - 70 z2 + 30 z3) 
   (0.9 (0 y1 + 90 y2 - 10 y3) + 0.1 (0 z1 + 90 z2 - 10 z3)));
cons = 
   {0 y1 - 10 y2 + 90 y3 >= 0 z1 - 10 z2 + 90 z3, 
   0 z1 - 70 z2 + 30 z3 >= 0 y1 - 70 y2 + 30 y3, 
   y1 + y2 + y3 == 1, 
   z1 + z2 + z3 == 1 , 
   y1 >= 0, y2 >= 0,  y3 >= 0,  
   z1 >= 0, z2 >= 0,  z3 >= 0};
vars = {y1, y2, y3, z1, z2, z3};
sol = Maximize[{f, cons}, vars]
```

I get the following message:

> NMaximize::nrnum the function value is not a real number

However, when I delete the powers of 0.9 and 0.1, I can get the solution.

Could you please help me solve this issue?

Comment: your code works as is. Try with a fresh session (`Quit[]`).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I can not reproduce the problem the user is experiencing; I suspect it is being caused by corrupted lexical elements in the OP's Mathematica notebook.

Answer (score 2):

Mentioned by @kglr, the given code works. But it does not satisfy the condition y1 >= 0.

```
Clear[f, y1, y2, y3, z1, z2, z3];
f = ((0 y1 - 10 y2 + 90 y3)^(0.9) (0 z1 - 70 z2 + 
  30 z3) (0.9 (0 y1 + 90 y2 - 10 y3) + 
  0.1 (0 z1 + 90 z2 - 10 z3)));
cons = {0 y1 - 10 y2 + 90 y3 >= 0 z1 - 10 z2 + 90 z3, 
0 z1 - 70 z2 + 30 z3 >= 0 y1 - 70 y2 + 30 y3, y1 + y2 + y3 == 1, 
z1 + z2 + z3 == 1, y1 >= 0, y2 >= 0, y3 >= 0, z1 >= 0, z2 >= 0, 
z3 >= 0};
vars = {y1, y2, y3, z1, z2, z3};
sol = Maximize[{f, cons}, vars]

(*   {14949.8, {y1 -> -7.92921*10^-13, y2 -> 0.382254, y3 -> 0.617746, 
                z1 -> 0.424727, z2 -> 1.63087*10^-11, z3 -> 0.575273}}   *)
```

The reason is, that one term of f can get complex.

```
Rationalize[f, 0]

(*   (-10 y2 + 90 y3)^(9/10)* 
     (9/10 (90 y2 - 10 y3) + 1/10 (90 z2 - 10 z3))*(-70 z2 + 30 z3)   *)
```

Get conditions for the first term to be real

```
Reduce[(-10 y2 + 90 y3)^(9/10) == a && a \[Element] Reals, Reals]

(*   y2 <= 9 y3 && a == 10^(9/10) (-y2 + 9 y3)^(9/10)   *)
```

Add this additional conditon to get a slightly different result, satisfying conditions

```
cons2 = Join[cons, {y2 <= 9 y3}]

sol2 = Maximize[{f, cons2}, vars]

(*   {14949.8, {y1 -> 3.3758*10^-9, y2 -> 0.382254, y3 -> 0.617746, 
                z1 -> 0.424727, z2 -> 2.69121*10^-9, z3 -> 0.575273}}   *)
```

**Appendix:**

If you have

```
g = ((0 y1 - 10 y2 + 90 y3)^(0.9) (0 z1 - 70 z2 + 
  30 z3)^0.1 (0.9 (0 y1 + 90 y2 - 10 y3) + 
 0.1 (0 z1 + 90 z2 - 10 z3)))
```

or `Rationalize[g, 0]`

```
(*    (-10 y2 + 90 y3)^(9/10) 
      (9/10 (90 y2 - 10 y3) + 1/10 (90 z2 - 10 z3)) 
      (-70 z2 + 30 z3)^(1/10)
```

you have to force the product to be real and get as general answer

```
Reduce[(-10 y2 + 90 y3)^(9/10) *(-70 z2 + 30 z3)^(1/10) == a && 
         a \[Element] Reals, Reals]

(*   z2 <= (3 z3)/7 && y2 <= 9 y3 && 
     a == 10 (-y2 + 9 y3)^(9/10) (-7 z2 + 3 z3)^(1/10)   *)

cons3 = Join[cons, {z2 <= (3 z3)/7, y2 <= 9 y3}]

sol3 = Maximize[{g, cons3}, vars]

(*   {1274.45, {y1 -> 3.73318*10^-11, y2 -> 0.504878, y3 -> 0.495122, 
                z1 -> 0.560976, z2 -> 1.77067*10^-9, z3 -> 0.439024}}   *)
```

In general, you can also get real values of g, if both terms of `(-10 y2 + 90 y3)^(9/10) *(-70 z2 + 30 z3)^(1/10)` are complex. But to my intuition these are only single points. My be someone else likes to examine this further.

Comment: Thanks for your help Akku14. could you please let me know how did you get the following condition: cons2 = Join[cons, {y2 <= 9 y3}] Also, in the above problem, just the first term of objective function has the power of 0.9. if the second term has a power of (0.1), do I need to do the same steps that you mentioned for the second term as well: I mean if the objective function is: f = ((0 y1 - 10 y2 + 90 y3)^(0.9) (0 z1 - 70 z2 + 30 z3)^0.1 (0.9 (0 y1 + 90 y2 - 10 y3) + 0.1 (0 z1 + 90 z2 - 10 z3))); Again thanks

Comment: The condition y2 <= 9 y3 directly follows as answer of the `Reduce[...` , if you force a to be real. Second, if you also have a power of 0.1 term, things get more complicated. See appendix to my answer.

Comment: Akku14, thanks. that works.

Comment: I am sorry for taking your time. I am new in Mathematica.

Comment: I am trying the model with another numerical example and still  I get error:Here is my code:

Comment: g = ((500 y1 + 1595 y2 - 405 y3)^(0.9) (700 z1 + 1757 z2 - 
      243 z3)^0.1 (0.9 (900 y1 - 121 y2 + 1879 y3) + 
     0.1 (900 z1 - 121 z2 + 1879 z3)))
Rationalize[g, 0]
Reduce[(500 y1 + 1595 y2 - 405 y3)^(9/10) (700 z1 + 1757 z2 - 
       243 z3)^(1/10) == a && a \[Element] Reals, Reals]

Comment: cons = {500 y1 + 1595  y2 - 405 y3 >= 500 z1 + 1595 z2 - 405 z3   ,  
  700 z1 + 1757 z2 - 243 z3 >= 700 y1 + 1757 y2 - 243 y3  , 
  y1 + y2 + y3 == 1, z1 + z2 + z3 == 1, y1 >= 0, y2 >= 0, y3 >= 0, 
  z1 >= 0, z2 >= 0, z3 >= 0}
cons3 = Join[
  cons, {z1 >= (1/700) (-1757 z2 + 243 z3),  
   y1 >= (1/100) (-319 y2 + 81 y3)}]
vars = {y1, y2, y3, z1, z2, z3}
sol3 = Maximize[{g, cons3}, vars]

Comment: This is the error: "the function is not a real number  at (y1,y2,y3,z1,z2,z3)"

Comment: Could you please help me about this issue also.

Comment: @Akku14 I really appreciate if you help me regrading my question.  I have *g = ((500 y1 + 1595 y2 - 405 y3)^(0.9) (700 z1 + 1757 z2 - 243 z3)^0.1 (0.9 (900 y1 - 121 y2 + 1879 y3) + 0.1 (900 z1 - 121 z2 + 1879 z3)))   cons = {500 y1 + 1595 y2 - 405 y3 >= 500 z1 + 1595 z2 - 405 z3 , 700 z1 + 1757 z2 - 243 z3 >= 700 y1 + 1757 y2 - 243 y3 , y1 + y2 + y3 == 1, z1 + z2 + z3 == 1, y1 >= 0, y2 >= 0, y3 >= 0, z1 >= 0, z2 >= 0, z3 >= 0}  *cons3 = Join[ cons, {z1 >= (1/700) (-1757 z2 + 243 z3), y1 >= (1/100) (-319 y2 + 81 y3)}]*  still I am getting error which says my function value is not real. Thanks